# Nexus 7 4.2.2 canvas drawtext letters f and j wont display

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw, drawtext, nexus-7

I have odd behaviour on my Nexus 7

I have been using Sassoon Primary ttf to draw a single letter using drawText on the center of a canvas in my own view. This has been working fine on all models I have tested except my nexus 7.

all letters still work except lower-case f and j

I have tested on 4.2.2 emulator and it works fine as well as 4.0.3 , 4.1.2 and 2.3

For good measure I have set it back to default font and it now draws F but not J.

Has anyone had the same problem or can recreate?

My Paint

```
        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextSize(650);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setTypeface(font);
        textPaint.setDither(true);
```

the onDraw command

```
            canvas.drawText(letter, center, center, textPaint);
```

EDIT: turns out its the size 650, which i need it to be. When lowered this then worked. How can I keep it at the size I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a font size that's way too big to fit in the font cache. You could use a combination of a smaller font size and a scale transform on Canvas to achieve the effect you want. You could also use a software layer (see `View.setLayerType()`) on the View that draws the letter.

Comment: Thanks but how come this works on all other versions including emulator of 4.2.2?  just playing around with setLayerType

Comment: setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); has worked thank you

Comment: The emulator, by default, runs with software rendering.